# sharepoint 2010 site columns don't show up in word 2007 quick parts

Tags: sharepoint

I'm working on a clients SharePoint platform and they need a set of templates bound to some content types.

I have the whole thing working but as soon as I choose edit template,from the content type advanced settings menu to add quick parts to the template. I get some columns in the quick parts dialog in word, but not all of them. Also some other ones not associated to the content type.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Could you provide a simple example of the problem so we can see where you are going wrong?

Comment: Hi @hosch250, thanks for replying.

So these are some of my site columns, there a lot so I posted an image of some, created in the root:
http://s2.postimg.org/72osacba1/contenttype.png

Then these columns are associated to this content type:
http://s2.postimg.org/zd0edytcp/sitecolumns.png

When editing the word template from the advanced settings, I get these quick parts to work with:
http://s2.postimg.org/np6cjf47t/template.png

Hope that clearifies it a bit.

Comment: oops, first two screenshots are in the wrong order